# Solr, null values not present on the response

Tags: database, solr

I'm loading data from sql server to Solr(version 7.7.2) with DataImportHandler. I have 2 tables include different columns.

```
<document>
<entity name="users"
query="SELECT * FROM Users">
 <field column="IndexId" name="IndexId" />  
 <field column="Id" name="IdUsers"/>
 <field column="name" name="name"/>
 <field column="location" name="location"/>   
</entity>

<entity name="products" query="SELECT Id,ISNULL(name, 'default') as name,ISNULL(size, 'default') as size FROM products">
 <field column="IndexId" name="IndexId" />  
 <field column="Id" name="IdProducts"/>   
 <field column="name" name="name"/>   
 <field column="size" name="size"/>   
</entity>
</document>
```

some records on my DB are null, and it's not present in the solr query response. I want to show the column name and its value even if it's null on the solr response.

I try to use `default=""` on the fields. but it returns all fields on the schema.xml. I want only fields on specific table fields to be returned based on the query. How can accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In sql query, you can use ISNULL function to return the alternate value for the column.

```
SELECT ISNULL(IndexId, ""),ISNULL(Id,"") FROM Users
```

Above query will return empty string where the values are null and that empty string will gets indexed into Solr.

Comment: the above solution returns ```org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Data Config problem: Element type "entity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Comment: Well this was just a sample query. If you want to use it inside the entity query attribute then you need to escape the quotes only then it will work.

Comment: still the empty string doesn't show on the response. I found ```solr.RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory processor factory removes empty fields from the documents we send to indexation.``` but didn't know to fix it

Comment: In that case, instead of empty string why don't you return some value. Something like this ISNULL(IndexId, "default") which will gets Indexed.

Comment: thanks, it works after changing the value to "default"